# SQLite query delay

Tags: sqlite, optimization

I have a very simple query:

```
SELECT count(id), min(id), max(id), sum(size), sum(frames), sum(catalog_size + file_size)
FROM table1
```

`table1` holds around 3000 to 4000 records.

My problem is that it takes around 20 seconds to this query to run. And since it is called more than once, the delay is pretty obvious to the customer.

Is it normal to this query to take 20 seconds? Is there any way to improve the run time?
If I run this same query from SQLite Manager it takes milliseconds to execute. The delay only occurs if the query is called from our software. `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` didn't help much. We use SQLite 3.7.3 version and Windows XPe.

Any thoughts how to troubleshoot this issue or improve the performance of the query?

Comment: Do you have an index on `id`?

Comment: Indexes aren't going to matter here.  It's still going to have to read every record in the table.  If the only aggregates were the `count(id), min(id), max(id)`, then the planner could use the index.  The `sum()`s after that mean the entire table has to be walked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the `sum`s require that every single record in the table must be read.

If the table contains more columns than those shown above, then the data read from the disk contains both useful and useless values (especially if you have big blobs). In that case, you can try to reduce the data needed to be read for this query by creating a [covering index](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx) over exactly those columns needed for this query.
In SQLite versions before 3.7.15, you need to add an `ORDER BY` for the first index field to force SQLite to use that index, but this doesn't work for all queries. (For your query, try updating to [this beta](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite3-20121009.zip), or wait for 3.7.15.)

Comment: you are correct, I do have much more columns than this query requires including blobs. Your suggestion sounds like a very good idea, unfortunately adding covering index doesn't seem to effect the query run time.

Comment: Use [`EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN'](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html) to check if the index gets used. Before 3.7.15, the SQLite query planner doesn't use one if not needed for sorting or grouping.

Comment: Thank you for these ideas. According to 'EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN' the index does not get used and I am not able to force SQLite to use it. I haven't tried the 3.7.15 upgrade yet.

Comment: Actually, if I am changing my query to 
`SELECT id, size, frames, catalog_size, file_size from table1`
will it still read all the columns or only those mentioned in the query?

Comment: It will read all table records, unless it is using a covering index.